# The Nested Set Model hierarchical data

Tags: mysql

I've a simple question.

My database structure is:

```
id | name | left | right // no need to tell me that left, right are reserved keywords
```

The only data in the database:

```
1 | family | 1 | 2
```

Now, I want to add new `child` to the family: `mother`. So theoretically I should take the right value of the element to which I want to add the child and free-up some space after it.

```
UPDATE `hp_tree` SET `right`=`right`+2 WHERE `right` > 2;
UPDATE `hp_tree` SET `left`=`left`+2 WHERE `left` > 2;
```

And then simply insert the child `mother`:

```
INSERT INTO `hp_tree` SET `left`=2, `right`=3, `name`='Mother';
```

Now, the problem is, that this way the `family` (root element) `right` value is not updated. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found this explained in [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). See the part starting with *If we instead want to add a node as a child of a node that has no existing children*.