# How can I search upto sub level categories using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, select, categories, product

I have a database of 30000 products and all products has assigned different categories. There is a separate table for all categories & sub-categories are also stored into same table.
The table structure is something like this

### Category_mst

category_id_pk, category_name, parent_id

### Product_mst

product_id_pk, product_name, category_id_fk (reference to Category_mst->category_id_pk)

Categories are stored upto any number of sub levels. 
So there can be categories like below

Clothes > Shirts > Kids > Red Color

Products are stored on any level of Category.
I want to make a query or a php script that can find out all the Categories that have no Products under it(upto any sub level).

How can I do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can get `category_id_pk` for each sub category, use `OR` statement in your SQL ("select product_id_pk from product_mst where category_id_pk=X OR category_id_pk=Y OR category_id_pk=Z"). Then use mysql_num_rows();

Comment: I'd suggest you to change your database design to make your life easier. Check this article http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/database-design/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to store hierarchical data in a database.
The naive approach to this is a very poor one, because MySQL does not support recursive queries (unlike Oracle or SQL-server).
Change your database design.

See: [The Nested Set Model hierarchical data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345837/the-nested-set-model-hierarchical-data)
[Implementing a hierarchical data structure in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544632/implementing-a-hierarchical-data-structure-in-a-database)